# unable to update counter when deleting and creating new section jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
/*creates phoens dynamically*/

var phoneList = [];

function add_phone() {
  var index = phoneList.length+1;
    phoneList.push('phone: '+index);
    var divtest = '<div class="form-group removeclass'+index+'">'+
    '<span class="help-block" style="font-weight: 400; font-size: 14px;">Phone ( '+index+' )</span>'+
    '<div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">'+
    '<div class="form-group">'+
    ' <input type="text" class="form-control" name="a[]" value="" placeholder="Type"></div></div>'+
    '<div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group">'+
    '<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="b[]" value="" placeholder="Model"></div>'+
    '</div><div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">'+
    '<div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="c[]" value="" placeholder="Color">'+
    '</div></div><div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group"><div class="input-group"> '+
    '<select class="form-control" name="d[]">'+
    '<option value="">Year</option><option value="2015">2015</option><option value="2016">2016</option>'+
    '<option value="2017">2017</option><option value="2018">2018</option> </select><div class="input-group-btn"> '+
    '<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="remove_phone('+ index +');"> <span '+
    'class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button></div></div></div></div><div '+
    'class="clear"></div>';

     $('#education_fields').append(divtest);
    updatePhonePicker();
}
   function remove_phone(rid) {
     $("#phone_picker option[value='"+rid+"']").remove();
     $('.removeclass'+rid).remove(); 
     phoneList.splice(phoneList.indexOf(rid),1);
     updatePhonePicker();
   }

   function updatePhonePicker(){
    var options = '<option selected disabled>---</option>';
    phoneList.forEach(function(element, index){
       options+='<option value="'+element+'">'+element+'</option>'
    })
    $('#tab_logic').find('tr').each(function(ind,ele){
     var r = $(ele).find("#phone_picker").empty().append(options);
    });
      
   }

/*Add details about phone added here*/
$(document).ready(function(){
      var i=1;
     $("#add_row").click(function(){
      $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><select class='form-control' title='Phone' id='phone_picker'><option selected disabled>---</option></select> </td><td><input  name='mail"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='field 1'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input  name='mobile"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='field 2'  class='form-control input-md'></td>");

      $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
      i++; 
      updatePhonePicker();
  });
     $("#delete_row").click(function(){
       if(i>1){
     $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
     i--;
     }
   });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Add Phone-->
  <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading">Phone Information</div>
     <div class="panel-body">
     
     <div id="education_fields">
             
    </div>
     
 
     <div class="input-group">
         <div class="input-group-btn">
           <span class="help-block" style="font-weight: 400; font-size: 14px;">Add Phone.</span>
           <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"  onclick="add_phone();"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
         </div>
       </div>
   </div>
  </div>
    
   
  <!--Individual phone information-->
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
       <span class="help-block" style="font-weight: 400; font-size: 14px;">Phone selected additional details.</span>
     <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th class="text-center">
         #
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
         Phone
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
         Type
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
         Carrier
        </th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr id='addr0'>
        <td>
        1
        </td>
        <td>
        <select class="form-control" title="Phone" id="phone_picker">
             <option selected disabled>---</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder='field 1' class="form-control"/>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder='field 2' class="form-control"/>
        </td>
       </tr>
                      <tr id='addr1'></tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
   <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Phone</a><a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Phone</a>
  </div>
```

When clicking on 'Add Phone', I get the option to add as many phones as needed. Phone count (How many phones created) get added on the 'Phone selected additional details' select option when adding or removing a new phone.

My issue is that when I create 3 phone sections then remove phone #1 and add another phone again it give me the same phone counter (example added 1,2,3 removed 1 added another one get 1 and 1 again and it should be like that, it should be a unit counter(phone) everytime).

To be more specific steps go as follow:

1. click on 'add phone' one time and a 2nd time and a 3rd time.
2. click on the red button where it's title 'Phone(1)'.
3. check if the number of phone present match what is on the 'Phone' select/dropdown.
4. You will see that the number of phone display doesn't match what on select.

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
 var index = phoneList.length+1;
```

Because you create new div with a class like removeclass1, removeclass2..... you can consider to get directly the last div and so extract the number instead to increment by one:

```
var index = 1;
if ($('#education_fields > div').length > 0) {
    index = 1 + +$('#education_fields > div:last').attr('class').match(/.*removeclass(\d+).*/)[1];
}
```

From your comment:

> Ok this is good but if you look down the table column 'Phone' and the select/dropdown, it seems not be getting updated when deleting 'phone'/section

You can change **updatePhonePicker** in order to build dynamically the options getting the data directly from the divs:

From:

```
phoneList.forEach(function(element, index){
    options+='<option value="'+element+'">'+element+'</option>'
})
```

to:

```
$('#education_fields > div > span').each(function(idx, ele) {
    var txt = ele.textContent.replace(/[()]/g, '').trim();
    options+='<option value="'+txt+'">'+txt+'</option>'
})
```

```js
var phoneList = [];

function add_phone() {
    var index = 1;
    if ($('#education_fields > div').length > 0) {
        index = 1 + +$('#education_fields > div:last').attr('class').match(/.*removeclass(\d+).*/)[1];
    }
    phoneList.push('phone: '+index);
    var divtest = '<div class="form-group removeclass'+index+'">'+
            '<span class="help-block" style="font-weight: 400; font-size: 14px;">Phone ( '+index+' )</span>'+
            '<div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">'+
            '<div class="form-group">'+
            ' <input type="text" class="form-control" name="a[]" value="" placeholder="Type"></div></div>'+
            '<div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group">'+
            '<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="b[]" value="" placeholder="Model"></div>'+
            '</div><div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">'+
            '<div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="c[]" value="" placeholder="Color">'+
            '</div></div><div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group"><div class="input-group"> '+
            '<select class="form-control" name="d[]">'+
            '<option value="">Year</option><option value="2015">2015</option><option value="2016">2016</option>'+
            '<option value="2017">2017</option><option value="2018">2018</option> </select><div class="input-group-btn"> '+
            '<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="remove_phone('+ index +');"> <span '+
            'class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button></div></div></div></div><div '+
            'class="clear"></div>';

    $('#education_fields').append(divtest);
    updatePhonePicker();
}
function remove_phone(rid) {
    $("#phone_picker option[value='"+rid+"']").remove();
    $('.removeclass'+rid).remove();
    phoneList.splice(phoneList.indexOf(rid),1);
    updatePhonePicker();
}

function updatePhonePicker(){
    var options = '<option selected disabled>---</option>';
    $('#education_fields > div > span').each(function(idx, ele) {
        var txt = ele.textContent.replace(/[()]/g, '').trim();
        options+='<option value="'+txt+'">'+txt+'</option>'
    })
    $('#tab_logic').find('tr').each(function(ind,ele){
        var r = $(ele).find("#phone_picker").empty().append(options);
    });

}

/*Add details about phone added here*/
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=1;
    $("#add_row").click(function(){
        $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><select class='form-control' title='Phone' id='phone_picker'><option selected disabled>---</option></select> </td><td><input  name='mail"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='field 1'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input  name='mobile"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='field 2'  class='form-control input-md'></td>");

        $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
        i++;
        updatePhonePicker();
    });
    $("#delete_row").click(function(){
        if(i>1){
            $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
            i--;
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!--Add Phone-->
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Phone Information</div>
    <div class="panel-body">

        <div id="education_fields">

        </div>


        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <span class="help-block" style="font-weight: 400; font-size: 14px;">Add Phone.</span>
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"  onclick="add_phone();"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!--Individual phone information-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12 column">
            <span class="help-block" style="font-weight: 400; font-size: 14px;">Phone selected additional details.</span>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">
                        #
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-center">
                        Phone
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-center">
                        Type
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-center">
                        Carrier
                    </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr id='addr0'>
                    <td>
                        1
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select class="form-control" title="Phone" id="phone_picker">
                            <option selected disabled>---</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" placeholder='field 1' class="form-control"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" placeholder='field 2' class="form-control"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id='addr1'></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Phone</a><a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Phone</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok this is good but if you look down the table column 'Phone' and the select/dropdown, it seems not be getting updated when deleting 'phone'/section

Comment: @MayrenMartinez  Answer and snippet updated. Let me know. Thanks

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for your help dude!.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to write another function like the `updatePhonePicker()` where you gonna update the numbers displayed inside the `<span>`

Here is the function:

1-First surround the counter display in a span and give it a class (counterClass): `....Phone <span class="counterClass">( '+index+' )</span>`

2- Each row give it a class (.someClass)

```
 function updatePhoneNumbers(){
      var counter = i;
      $('someClass').forEach(function(element, index){
          var number = i-counter+1;
          $(element).find('.counterClass').html(counter);
          counter--;
      })
  }
```

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: check the answer out

Comment: someClass? refer to code and explain which someClass. I'm lost. Thanks for the help tho.

Comment: I have explained that you have to give every row a class (which is in my case 'someClass') you can give it any class you want:
`var divtest = '<div class="form-group someClass removeclass'+index+'">...`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the first line of add_phone

```
var index = phoneList.length+1;
```

I would remove the "+1", because if you add your first item it get's the html class removeclass1, but has the index 0 in the phoneList array. To remove this phone you call removePhone(1), but actually its index is 0, so you remove no phone or rather a wrong phone.